# Refinancing Loans from USA to India

Tags: united-states, india, loans, refinance, business

I have a friend living in USA who is a US citizen. He can take a loan of X$ from a US bank as a personal loan or a business loan. Can he finance my company in India with this loan he availed from USA ?

Answer (score 1):

On a personal Loan Yes. On a business loan, it would depend on the Bank and they would like to understand the purpose of the loan and need it to be secured. They may not even grant such kind of business loan.

Answer (score 0):

Most personal loans in the US are for the purpose of *purchasing*
some tangible object (usually a house or car) and that object is
the *collateral* for the loan. Indeed, the loan *proceeds* are usually
paid directly to the seller without passing through the bank account
of the borrower, and the seller delivers the title of the car
to the lender, or a mortgage lien is recorded on the real property.
Except possibly in the case of a refinance of a home mortgage, 
there is not much *cash* from such a loan
to send to a friend to invest in his business, whether in the US
or in India.  These types of loans are "relatively easy" to get.

Much harder to get are *unsecured* personal loans. Unless your
friend has a very friendly banker, getting an unsecured
loan of, say, $20,000 "just for the heck of it" is not easy.
Some reasonably well-off people do manage to get such loans
and use the money to *invest* in the stock or bond markets, in which
case, the *interest* paid on such loans can be deducted on 
Schedule A (but only to the extent of the actual investment
income; any extras can be carried over to the next year).
So, will your friend be *investing* in your business or making
a *loan* to your business? and do you anticipate that your business
will generate any *investment income* or *interest* for your
friend? If not, and your friend *still* wants to finance your
business (while making payments on the loan in the US), then your friend
must really like you a lot (or have faith that a few years down the
road, you will be able to sell your business to GoAppTel
for mucho big bucks and pay him off very handsomely).